# No renderer found for "text/markdown" a

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am getting the error 'No renderer found for "text/markdown" a' when trying to render a Markdown cell of VSCode's Jupyter Notebook. I am using VSCode v1.60.1
Code cells are working fine.

Comment: There was a recent issue filed against `microsoft/vscode` that suggests you [might have disabled this functionality](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132788#issuecomment-920462271).

Comment: Thanks very much. That was the reason. The inbuilt "Markdown Language Features" extension was disabled.